# I dont know how can use this regex in java

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the next regex, that works when I test online in: http://www.regexr.com/ but not works on my java project:

```
(?:function jo|[{;]jo\s*=\s*function)\((.*?[a-z,]+)\){(.*?[^}]+)}
```

My code:

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(?:function "+funcname+"|[{;]"+funcname+"\\s*=\\s*function)\\((.*?[a-z,]+)\\){(.*?[^}]+)}");
```

My error:

```
07-23 23:43:17.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1724): (?:function jo|[{;]jo\s*=\s*function)\((.*?[a-z,]+)\){(.*?[^}]+)}
07-23 23:43:17.608: E/AndroidRuntime(1724):                                                        ^
```

My example test string:

```
{return a.reverse()}};function jo(a){a=a.split("");a=io.aS(a,53);a=io.Y7(a,19);a=io.aS(a,9);a=io.km(a,2);a=io.Y7(a,29);a=io.km(a,1);return a.join("")};function ko(){};var lo
```

I want extract this part:

```
a=a.split("");a=io.aS(a,53);a=io.Y7(a,19);a=io.aS(a,9);a=io.km(a,2);a=io.Y7(a,29);a=io.km(a,1);return a.join("")
```

Thanks a lot, I am coming crazy with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I just want to say that using regex to parse code is not best idea. You should search for parser and use it instead.</sub>

It seems that you forgot to escape `{` and `}` at the end of your regex. You need to escape them since they are regex metacharacters used to specify how many times something can appear like

- `a{4}` - means that `a` must appear exactly 4 times
- `a{2,4}` - means that `a` must appear 2, 3 or 4 times
- `a{2,}` - means that `a` must appear 2 or more times.

Try with

```
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(?:function " + funcname + "|[{;]"
        + funcname + "\\s*=\\s*function)\\((.*?[a-z,]+)\\)\\{(.*?[^}]+)\\}");
// parts changed                                          ^^^          ^^^
```

Demo:

```
String text = "{return a.reverse()}};function jo(a){a=a.split(\"\");a=io.aS(a,53);a=io.Y7(a,19);a=io.aS(a,9);a=io.km(a,2);a=io.Y7(a,29);a=io.km(a,1);return a.join(\"\")};function ko(){};var lo";

String funcname = Pattern.quote("jo");// lets excape potential regex
                                      // special characters

Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(?:function " + funcname + "|[{;]"
        + funcname + "\\s*=\\s*function)\\((.*?[a-z,]+)\\)\\{(.*?[^}]+)\\}");

Matcher m = p2.matcher(text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

Output:

```
a=a.split("");a=io.aS(a,53);a=io.Y7(a,19);a=io.aS(a,9);a=io.km(a,2);a=io.Y7(a,29);a=io.km(a,1);return a.join("")
```

Comment: Thanks! Regex are complex and use them in java is more difficult :) I want add that I have to extratc 2st group.

Comment: I updated answer to add example of how to get part you wanted. Also generally it is better to use parser to parse code. You will not be able to use regex if your code would contain some inner classes or nexted blocks.